# PHP - Select & Update statement to return and update a multi dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I have a database that looks like the following

[image: table contents]

In my database both id & fb_user_id are unique. Id is an auto incremented number.

First i would like to insert a new row for arguments say with the following

```
$new_first_name = "John";
$new_last_name = "Nolan";
$new_email = "John@Nolan.com";
$new_link_url = "Johns_Link";
$new_signups = 0;
$new_order = $num_rows;
$referred_by = 2;
$new_fb_user_id = 4;
```

I use this insert statement

```
$New_Member = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `rotator`.`rotator` (`id`, `fb_user_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `link_url`, `referred_by`, `signups`, `order`) VALUES (NULL, '$new_fb_user_id', '$new_first_name', '$new_last_name', '$new_email', '$new_link_url', '$referred_by', '$new_signups', '$new_order');");
```

And because the person was referred by fb_user_id number 2 i want to update signups as follows

```
$update_sponsor_order = mysql_query("UPDATE `rotator`.`signups` = `rotator`.`signups` + 1 WHERE `rotator`.`fb_user_id` = $referred_by;");
```

This is where i am stuck. Maybe there is a better way to do it than inserting and updating the table as abovee.

What i would like to do now is something like the following select statement but assigning the returned values to a multi dimensional array. Basically i return columns fb_user_id and order where signups is less than 2

```
$get_link = mysql_query("SELECT `rotator`.`fb_user_id`, `rotator`.`order` FROM `rotator`.`rotator` WHERE `rotator`.`signups` < 2);
```

Now with my array i want to rotate everything that is in the column order and update the database of what entry is next in line....

Check the following question and replys to see what i am trying to do

[Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117872/php-rotate-and-adding-to-an-array)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: what you want is a trigger. Read about them here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Comment: I learned php via google a long time ago and i suppose i do need to start over again or do a course..... Is there anyway either of you could help me out with this

Answer (score 2):

You're new best friend the pdo class. I know this doesn't exactly answer your question, but if you start using it now, you will thank me later.

Overview here http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php

And to retreive results: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: Anyway you could help me out.... Would take me forever to learn how to use PDO statements and i need to get this done asap